# About divergence of a vector field and geodesic sphere

Tags: general-relativity

I have a question. I want to know the difference between the sphere and the geodesic sphere.
Another question:
given a vector field, $Y$, on a manifold $M$ defined by: $Y(p)=p$ for every point $p \in M$, I tried to calculate the divergence of $Y$. I think that it is equal to $n$, where $n$ is the dimension of $M$, but I don't know exactly how I can compute it.

Comment: What does $Y(p)=p$ mean? (Here $p$ is a point in a manifold $M$ and $Y(p)\in T_pM$.)

Comment: This is what it make me crazzy, he says that let choose a radial vector field Y defie by ... and he puts this expression, after he considers a a vector field Y in hyperbolic space H define by for each point p of H, Y(p)=-a-g(a,p)p where a is a point of H. The problem is as you sayed Y is a vector and the right quantites are points. I don't know what he means by this written.

Comment: Yes yu re right,he puts this expression, after he considers a a vector field Y in hyperbolic space H define by for each point p of H, Y(p)=-a-g(a,p)p where a is a point of H. The problem is as you sayed Y is a vector and the right quantites are points. I don't know what he means by this written. This cours is a seminar where our prof give as some lectures of an article of J.L.ALIAS this is the link: http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0311352                          this problem is in the last paragraph of page 18 and the first one of page 19.